# Shortcuts stopped to work

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts, sublime-text

I have Ubuntu 13.10.

2 hours ago I installed latest updated. (All remember about update is that it was 13MB size)
and rebooted.

Now my shortcuts do not work as expected.

First, I was switching Language with `Alt+SPACE`.
`Alt+SPACE` is still selected in All Settings - Text Entry

But when I press it I get top right windows menu like on Windows. 
I was not getting it few hours ago.

Then `Sublime Text 2` `CTRL+DOT`,`CTRL+P` works like I just press `CTRL+P`.
Seems like it is the only way to get Package Installer.
May be `CTRL+DOT` is hooked by OS and `Sublime Text 2` is not getting that input.

Any idea what could happen with shortcuts and how can I roll back to old behavior?

**UPDATE**

I went throw `All Settings - Keyboard` and found that `ALT SPACE` activates Windows Menu. I disabled it. But `CTRL DOT` or `CTRL .` is not listed there.

Comment: CTRL DOT is not used by the OS.  I assume you mean the period - which one are you using?  I would assume the one on the numeric keypad would not be the one, as this would be CTRL DELETE. I know nothing about Sublime Text, and don't really want to, so I can't tell you anything about it.